# <span> background with font size

Tags: php, css, background, font-size, html

in site bbcode text background and size output like this

```
<span style="background: #ff0000;">

text size normal

<br></br>
<br></br>
<span style="font-size: 250%">

    text size big

</span>
<br></br>
<br></br>

</span>
```

the problem is background will not fit text size

http://jsfiddle.net/fr3wA/

http://img11.imageshack.us/img11/7199/sdpm.png

if I make the span inline block , the background color will be on the whole box

http://img31.imageshack.us/img31/323/d3t5.png

I know the background color will fit the text if I put the style in like this

```
<span style="background: #ff0000;">

text size normal

<br></br>
<br></br>
<span style="style="background: #ff0000;"font-size: 250%">

    text size big

</span>
<br></br>
<br></br>

</span>
```

my problem is the code generated from php bbcode and the user sometime choose background color before text size

Comment: It is likely that the style line-height is being set somewhere and inheriting in your big font area. Try also setting: line-height: 250%;

Comment: tried style="font-size: 250%; line-height: 250%;" but no change!

Comment: All of this bit of html is just so horrible...: 
`style="style="background: #ff0000;"font-size: 250%"`<-- what is this?; 

<br></br> __could__ be <br />, or even <br>, which looks nicer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just inherit the background from the previous span

```
<span style="background: #ff0000;">

text size normal

<br /><br />
<br /><br />
<span style="font-size: 250%; background: inherit;"> <!-- inherit the background -->

    text size big

</span>
<br /><br />
<br /><br />
```

Check out how it works here: http://jsfiddle.net/fr3wA/3/

Comment: @ArianFaurtosh - why do you use '%' units for font size? is this for different screen sizes?

Comment: @ghosh because the question contained it

Comment: @ArianFaurtosh I was asking 'what does it mean?'. I've googled it tnx